# I set my servlet-api.jar in classpath but when I import javax.servlet.http.*; it gives compilation error that this package does not exist why?

Tags: java, servlets

I set my servlet-api.jar in classpath, but when I call

```
import javax.servlet.http.*;
```

it gives compilation error that this package does not exist. Why?

```
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ShowServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException ,ServletException
    {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add information about your environment - are you working with an ide and if so with which one?

Comment: And how exactly do you "set my servlet-api.jar in classpath" ?

Comment: are you using any IDE?